# Proving series $\sum\frac{x}{1+n^2x}$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Question asks to show that series $\sum\frac{x}{1+n^2x}$ is uniformly convergent on $[\alpha,1]$ for any $\alpha > 0$ but is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$

I could show that the above series is uniformly convergent on $[\alpha,1], \alpha > 0$ by using inequality $\frac{x}{1+n^2x} < \frac{x}{1+n^2\alpha} = u_{n}$, which is convergent by Raabe's test and hence the series is uniformly convergent on $[\alpha,1]$ by Weierstrass M-test

But i am clueless how to show it non uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$

Comment: Consider all the terms where $x \leq 1/n^2$. Try to use them to show the sum is bounded below by $1/2$ as $x$ approaches 0.

Comment: if $x \leq \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ then $\frac{x}{2} \leq\frac{x}{1+n^2x}$ then how come it bounded below by $1/2$ ?